# Use of super keyword in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, super

I have doubt regarding **printing of superclass constructor statement** even when I have not used super() keyword in subclass.

```
class A
{
    int i;
    A()
    {
        System.out.println("A's constructor");
    }
}
class B extends A
{
    int i;
    B(int a , int b)
    {
        super.i=a;
        i=b;
    }
    void show()
    {
        System.out.println(super.i);
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
class UseSuper
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        B b=new B(1,2);
        b.show();
    }
}
```

The output of my program is:

> A's constructor
>
> 1
>
> 2

I am unable to understand why I am getting A's constructor printed on my console?

Comment: That's how java works. This is mainly done so that the parents properties are initialized before creating the child object so as to maintain the child object that has a consistent state.

Comment: A child can not comes to existence before its parent does.

Comment: `super()` is added automatically by compiler

Comment: I think super keyword is used for calling parent's class constructor but if parent's class constructor are automatically called then what is the use of super() keyword?

Comment: @NikhilBansal You can only avoid writing the super keyword if you redefine the constructor without arguments. But if the constructor of the parent class has arguments, you must pass them in the super() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following lines from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

---

> Note: If a constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass
>   constructor, the Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the
>   no-argument constructor of the superclass. If the super class does not
>   have a no-argument constructor, you will get a compile-time error.
>   Object does have such a constructor, so if Object is the only
>   superclass, there is no problem.
>
> ---
>
> If a subclass constructor invokes a constructor of its superclass,
>   either explicitly or implicitly, you might think that there will be a
>   whole chain of constructors called, all the way back to the
>   constructor of Object. In fact, this is the case. It is called
>   constructor chaining, and you need to be aware of it when there is a
>   long line of class descent.

I hope, it clears your doubts.

**[Update]**

Posting this update to clear OP's doubts he has mentioned in his comment below.

The following code won't compile because implicit super constructor `A()` has not been defined and we have also not defined it explicitly. Note that the implicit super constructor `A()` is automatically defined when there is no other constructor with arguments have been defined.

```
class A {
    int i;

    A(int x,int y){

    }
}

class B extends A {
    int i;

    B(int a, int b) {
        super.i = a;
        i = b;
    }

    void show() {
        System.out.println(super.i);
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}

public class UseSuper {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B(1, 2);
        b.show();
    }
}
```

**[Another Update]**

Posting this update to clear OP's another doubt which he has mentioned in his comment below.

The following code too won't compile because the super constructor `A()` has been declared as `private` preventing the child class constructor to call it.

```
class A {
    int i;

    private A() {
        System.out.println("A's constructor");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    int i;

    B(int a, int b) {
        super.i = a;
        i = b;
    }

    void show() {
        System.out.println(super.i);
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}

class UseSuper {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B(1, 2);
        b.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Suppose if there is no constructor present in my class A i.e only one instance variable a is present . Then according to your statement  "if super class does not have no argument constructor it will give compile time error" becomes false. Can you please explain this to me?

Comment: I think my doubt is cleared. Can you please confirm it that I am thinking in the right direction. Actually I was thinking that if I will remove the constructor completely from my class A then there will be no constructor left and it will start giving compile time error but I have forgotton about the concept of default constructor which is also a no argument constructor.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. A default constructor is provided when there is no other constructor with arguments is defined.

Comment: Can I prevent java to call parent's class constructors when I have not used super keyword?

Comment: No, we can't prevent Java to call parent's class constructors. It's against the OOP principle. A child can not comes to existence before its parent does. I've posted another update to clarify it further.

Answer (score 0):

When a class extends another class, it is crucial to first call the constructor of the parent class and initialize it, before calling the constructor of the current class.

Even when not visually calling `super()` in any part of your constructor, Java itself calls the constructor of class A.

Comment: If a superclass has a private constructor, it can't have inheritors.

Comment: Right, I knew something was off with my comment about the private constructor but wasn't sure, thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 0):

If a constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass constructor, the Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the no-argument constructor of the superclass. If the superclass does not have a no-argument constructor, you will get a compile-time error. Object does have such a constructor, so if Object is the only superclass, there is no problem.

In other words, constructor B(int a , int b) calls constructor A() implicitly. In IDE, just change A() to A(int i) and you'll see an error message for constructor B(int a , int b) like "Implicit super constructor A() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor".